# How to hide required message instantly when input field is not empty

Tags: jquery

There is an input filed. It it's empty, after clicking the "submit" button, it'll show a required message something like "This field is required". After touching the input and typing anything that required message should be gone as at the time of typing anything at the input field, that input field is not empty anymore. But, I can't hide that message instantly at the time of typing. It has been hidden after clicking the submit button again. But, I need hide instantly when filed is not empty anymore. How to do this? I have used:

```
if ($('#field').val() == '') {
      $('.required').show();
  } else {
     $('.required').hide();
  }
```

[Fiddle Work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/n05wc21b/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', formSubmit);
$('#field').keyup(isFormValid);

function isFormValid() {
    if ($('#field').val() == '') {
        $('.required').show();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.required').hide();
        return true;
    }
}
function formSubmit(){
    if(isFormValid()){
        alert('form is valid');
    }else{
        alert('form is not valid');
    }
}
```

Updated [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/n05wc21b/4/)

---

You would have to use [`.keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) and then do the same check you are doing on click.

Something like this

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', formCheck);
$('#field').keyup(formCheck);

function formCheck() {
    if ($('#field').val() == '') {
        $('.required').show();
    } else {
        $('.required').hide();
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/n05wc21b/1/)

Comment: Thanks, can you give me one more little favor? For testing another thing, I have added this type of functionality that when input is not empty, after clicking submit then, a new thing will be happened which I made at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/n05wc21b/2/
 But I don't understand how to put this after .keyup function

Comment: @Dhiraj Great answer, I up-voted but a quick question. Is there any advantage on using `($('#field').val() == '')` over simply  `(!$('#field').val())` in this particular case?

Comment: @TravisClarke: I don't think so. You can use either.

Comment: @user1896653: So you want something else to happen if the user enters the form correctly? I don't understand what that has to do with keyup

Comment: No, I don't work keyup to work after submit. I just want after submit, if the filed is not empty, a new thing will happen (I have brought popup for testing). So, I need basically these 3 things:
1) After click submit, if input is empty, show an empty message, 
2) After showing the empty message when anyone make the input not empty by touching and typing anything, empty message should gone instantly (like keyup function). 
3) And when the field is not empty, then after clicking submit, a completely new thing will happened(popup)

Comment: Yes, I want something else happened if the user enters the form correctly